# How do I insert data from one table to another in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a grid with records and them had a checkbox `<input name="id[]" value="<?php echo $valor->id ?>" type="checkbox" class="check" />` and I am trying to copy the selected record to another table

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `pendientes` SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE id = $idcopia"; 
mysql_query($sql);
```

but I don't know how to send the id, my idea is select a checkbox and with a button "Copy" send the id but maybe there is another way.

Comment: Are you having a problem with the PHP, SQL, or both? Your question is not greatly obvious.

Comment: Note: your code is SQL injectable. Remember [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score -1):

Most browsers don't send the checkbox's value, just the word `"on"`. To get around this, you can pass the "value" as a key to the array:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="id[<?php echo $valor->id; ?>]" class="check" />
```

Then on the PHP side:

```
$idlist = implode(",",array_map("intval",array_keys($_POST['id'])));
$sql = "INSERT INTO `pendientes` SELECT * FROM `clientes` WHERE `id` IN (".$idlist.")";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I created a button

<a href="copy.php?tab=<?php echo $_GET['tab'] ?>&id=<?php echo $valor->id ?>">copy</a>

and then in php

$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql="INSERT INTO `pendientes` SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE `id` IN '$id'";
$conn = DataBase::getInstance();
$conn->setQuery($sql);
$conn->execute();
mysql_close($db);

I had another button to delete and it's working but not with this, can u see something wrong in the code?

Comment: Since when do "most browser" not send the value? Huh?